# How to get coordinates of vertical string from pdf using java and pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox with java for finding the position or coordinates 0f the text from the pdf. The position of the text in horizontal is perfect, but the position of the vertical text is not accurate. Here is the code

```
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {

    String wordSeparator = getWordSeparator();
    List<TextPosition> word = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
        String thisChar = text.getUnicode();
        pageWid = text.getPageWidth();
        pageHe = text.getPageHeight();
        if (thisChar != null) {
            if (thisChar.length() >= 1) {
                if (!thisChar.equals(wordSeparator)) {
                    word.add(text);
                } else if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                    printWord(word);

                    word.clear();
                }

            }
        }

    }
    if (!word.isEmpty()) {

        printWord(word);
        word.clear();
    }

}

void printWord(List<TextPosition> word) {
    Rectangle2D boundingBox = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (TextPosition text : word) {

    /*  int rot =text.getRotation();
      System.out.println("rotation is "+rot);*/
        Rectangle2D box = new Rectangle2D.Float(text.getX(), text.getY(), text.getWidthDirAdj(),
                text.getHeightDir());

        if (boundingBox == null)
            boundingBox = box;
        else
            boundingBox.add(box);
        builder.append(text.getUnicode());
    }

    String words = builder.toString().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("the word is" + words + "length is" + words.length());

    if (words.length() != 1) {

        returncordinates(words, boundingBox.getX(), boundingBox.getY(), boundingBox.getHeight(),
                boundingBox.getWidth());
    }

}
```

using this code I am able to find the coordinates of the horizontal text:

Output  : thinking{'x':80.97092447794397,'y':36.56483345224815,'height':1.3265644959675444,'page_no':3,'width':6.51770994998429}

but when the text is horizontal the coordinates of vertical text is not coming accurate  (attached image).
[image]

Comment: The **x** and **y** coordinates you get from `getX` and `getY` are normalized for text analysis but not really usable for anything else. You should look at the coordinates in the transformation matrix in `TextPosition`.

Comment: Have a look at the `DrawPrintTextLocations.java` example.